# How to validate field doesnt contain . and ,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

I have a form which include number fields

```
<%= f.number_field :contribution_to_sales, class: 'form-control',:pattern=>["\d+"] %>
```

It allows 2.0 but I want it should not allow 2.0 . 
How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing anchors on your regular expression which causes the "2" in "2.0" to be matched (on some browsers). The regex to use is:

```
<%= ... pattern: "^\d+$" %>
```

You should probably be doing the validation on the model as well, as the HTML5 pattern attribute may not be obeyed by all browsers. Simply add:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :contribution_to_sales, numericality: { only_integer: true }
  ...
end
```

Comment: it doesnt allow 6.05 but it allos 6.0 still

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to the Model this form relies on:

```
 validate :format_numbers

   def format_numbers
      if self.number_field.include?(',') || self.number_field.include?('.')
         errors.add(base: "Do not add commas or periods please")
      end
   end
```

That is one way to validate however I prefer the much more user friendly way which removes certain things a user may add that I know I don't want and then continue to process the form instead of reporting back with an error.  This would be done by removing commas and since you don't want periods either I would imagine we can strip anything to the right of a period out as well.  To do it this way you would do the following in your Model instead of the above:

```
  validate :format_numbers


     def format_numbers
       self.number_field = self.number_field.gsub(/\.\d+/, '') #This will remove any period and all numbers to the right of that period.
       self.number_field = self.number_field.gsub(',','') #This will remove all commas throughout. 
     end
```

This provides a smoother user experience since they can now type 2,000.00 in the form field and it will be saved as 2000